# Rails console, wierd issue

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I type the following:

```
>> x.inspect
"\"53219847091d6601dd000004\""

>> "53219847091d6601dd000004".inspect
"\"53219847091d6601dd000004\""

 >> "53219847091d6601dd000004"==x
 false
```

They are the same so why they are not equal to each other?

Comment: They have the same value but they are not the same string object.

Comment: @mcfinnigan `"foo" == "foo"` returns `true`

Comment: what kind of object is `x`, i.e. what does `x.class` return?

Comment: Thanks guys, one was ObjectId the other plain string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inspect` returns a string representation of your object, its implementation is up to the class:

```
class Foo
  def inspect
    "I'm Foo"
  end
end

class Bar
  def inspect
    "I'm Foo"
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Bar.new

foo.inspect
#=> "I'm Foo"

bar.inspect
#=> "I'm Foo"
```

`foo` and `bar` have the same `inspect` value, but they are not equal:

```
foo == bar
#=> false
```

In fact, they are totally different objects:

```
foo.class #=> Foo
bar.class #=> Bar
```